# Determinant of a General Expression Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't really know how to do this question:

" Let $A = $
$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1& 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 1-x & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 1& 2-x &\cdots & 1 \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ 1& 1 & 1 &\cdots& n-1-x \end{pmatrix}$"

be an n×n matrix with n≥3. Solve the equation det(A)=0 of x∈R and find the largest root.

Comment: If you subtract the top row from each of the other rows, you don't change the determinant, and you make the matrix much simpler (full of zeros). Maybe you can find the determinant of the simpler matrix. If all else fails, find the determinant for a few small values of $n$, guess the general formula, and prove it by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the first column from the last, then $$\det A=\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1& 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1-x & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1& 2-x &\cdots & 1 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 1& 1 & 1 &\cdots& n-2-x & 0\\1& 1 & 1 &\cdots& 1 & n-2-x \end{pmatrix}=$$$$(n-2-x)\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1& 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 1-x & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 1& 2-x &\cdots & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1& 1 & 1 & \cdots& n-2-x \end{pmatrix}.$$ How can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

Errr does subtracting the first column from each of the remaining coliumns work? That should give $n-2$ as the largest root.